# Python regular expressions - either one character, or the other, or both

Tags: python, regex

given following string

`f = "803611662_249364_200825.csv"`

I want to extract all possible numbers, that could be handled as a date and surrounded by "_" andor ".",
in this case "*249364*" or "_200825."

My RE is:  `_[0-9]{6}[_?|.]`

So, first an underscore, then exactly 6 numbers (doesn't matter if date will be invalid), followed by either "_" or ".".
The [] is non greedy, so it'll only return the first match and not the second.

Expected output: `` ['_249364`_', '_200825.'] ``

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group with a positive lookahead to get only the numbers:

```
_(\d{6})(?=[._])
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hDpXEY/1)

Example

```
import re
 
s="803611662_249364_200825.csv"
pattern = "_(\d{6})(?=[._])"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['249364', '200825']
```

---

To get the values including the leading `_` and following `.` or `_` you can also use the capture group inside the lookahead:

```
(?=(_\d{6}[._]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zPuqdJ/1)

Example

```
import re
 
s="803611662_249364_200825.csv"
pattern = "(?=(_\d{6}[._]))"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['_249364_', '_200825.']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats exactly what i was looking for :)